# C# -- What are the exact differences between these two methods?

Tags: c#, methods

This is *not* a homework question.

If I were to describe the exact differences between the following two methods and their use in the caller, how would I do so?

Method 1:

```
public void WriteSpace(int numSpaces) {
        if (numSpaces <= 0) return;
        for (var x = 0; x < numSpaces; x++) {
            Response.Write(" ");
        }
    }
```

Method 2:

```
public String WriteSpaceReturn(int numSpaces) {
        var space = "";
        if (numSpaces <= 0) return space;
        for (var x = 0; x < numSpaces; x++) {
            space += " ";
        }
        return space;
    }
```

Caller:

```
WriteSpace(4); //1
Response.Write(WriteSpaceReturn(4)); //2
```

The end result is the same from both. So I realize obviously that the first method does not return a value to the caller whereas the second does, but beyond that, how else would I describe these?

Is there a difference in atomicity between the first & second methods? Scope? Blocking? Is there a name for the fact that the first method writes output inside the method, whereas the second lets the caller do that? If these were writing significant amounts of data, would one be preferred to the other? I suspect since the first is making a call to `Response.Write` for each character, it would be slower?

Comment: The first one has side effects. (Ie writing to the stream)

Comment: FYI: You could do this: `new string(' ', 10)`

Comment: @asawyer, could you clarify?

Comment: @user1991548 Mr Skeet has it covered (as usual)

Comment: I believe you should be using "&nbsp;" instead of " ". Browsers condense strings of multiple blank spaces into a single blank space, unless you use the non-blank space escape sequence.

Comment: @Kevin, output is wrapped in a pre tag, otherwise you're correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main difference in terms of performance: the second version of the code uses string concatenation in a loop, which is inefficient. I would *hope* that `Response.Write` would be more efficient than that.

Main difference in terms of encapsulation: the second form is a *pure method* - it has no side-effects. This makes it easier to test in isolation, and in this particular case makes it easier to use in multiple situations.

That's not to say the second version is *better* for being pure, necessarily - it depends on the context.

(In both cases you should remove the redundant check for `numSpaces` being non-positive.)

Answer (score 0):

One does the write for you (the first one)

The second one returns the string that the first one writes, requiring you to write it yourself.  Or, more importantly, allowing you to do any valid string related operation on it.

Answer (score 0):

This first method write the spaces directly to the response stream

The second creates a string containing the spaces.
The caller then has to write the spaces to the response: `Response.Write(WriteSpaceReturn(4));`

The latter is preferred as it provides more flex but the function can be completely replaced with:

```
new String(' ', 4 );
```

resulting in

```
Response.Write(new String(' ', 4 ));
```

Much more efficient and way clearer to read.

Comment: Single quotes needed, String constructor expects char.

Comment: @user1991548 Right! edit made